# Why .ents is not working on proper ways when i clall the function

Tags: python, nltk, spacy

```
import re
import spacy
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

inputfile = open('file.txt', 'r')
String= inputfile.read()
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

def candidate_name_extractor(input_string, nlp):
    input_string = str(input_string)

    doc = nlp(input_string)
    print(doc)
    # Extract entities
    doc_entities = doc.ents
    #print(doc_entities)
    # Subset to person type entities
    doc_persons = filter(lambda x: x.label_ == 'PERSON', doc_entities)
    doc_persons = filter(lambda x: len(x.text.strip().split()) >= 2, doc_persons)
    doc_persons = list(map(lambda x: x.text.strip(), doc_persons))
    candidate_name = doc_persons[0]
    return candidate_name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    names = candidate_name_extractor(String, nlp)

print(names)
```

When I run this program, and `print nlp(input_string)` then works fine. But when it execute the line `"doc_entities=doc.ents"`,

1. It removes upper three line which contain name mobile and email and
   I want to extract the name from it.

**where is problem Either `"doc_entities = doc.ents"` is not working on proper way or what?**

Comment: How do you propose we debug this without, say, an input string or `nlp`?

Comment: Again, no clue what your `file.txt` looks like.

Comment: @erip it's a text file of mine CV

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem here, because the multiple `filter`s make the example a bit hard to follow – but keep in mind that `doc.ents` returns a generator and not a list, so you might want to wrap it in a list `list(doc.ents)` to create a copy, before you start extracting from it. It might also make your code a little easier to debug if you replace the `doc_persons` extraction with a more straightforward `for` loop – at least, until you've figured out the problem (but of course, this mostly depends on personal preference).

Comment: @InesMontani I had try with lis(doc.ents) but output remain same.

Answer (score 0):

So I slightly rewrote your example to be a little more straightforward, and it's working fine for me. I think a lot of the problems you're experiencing might be related to the nested filtering and the string operations – which you can easily drop, because spaCy already does all of this for you.

Here, I'm simply iterating over the entities found in the text, and if the entity label is `PERSON`, and the entity consists of two or more token, we assume it's a person name and print the entity text. Each entry in `doc.ents` is a `Span` object, and its length is the length of tokens. So there's no need to split the string – you can simply use `len(ent)`.

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(u"John Smith")  # or whatever else

for ent in doc.ents:
    if ent.label_ == 'PERSON' and len(ent) >= 2:
        print('The candidate name is: ', ent.text)  # do something with the entity
```

Of course, this will only return a result if spaCy's model actually recognises that name as an entity. The default models are trained on general-purpose news and web text, so if you're processing a CV, you might not always get perfect results without fine-tuning on your use case.

It's not entirely clear from your question what you want to do with the phone number or email address – but all of this information will still be available in your `doc`. For example, let's say you also wanted to extract an email address, the easiest way to do this would be to use the `like_email` attribute on the token:

```
doc = nlp(u"John Smith, john@smith.com")
email_addresses = [token.text for token in doc if token.like_email]
# ['john@smith.com']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. But when i put doc = nlp(u"Jay Pratap Pandey") it doesn't return any thing.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely possible – the models are statistical and the entities they recognise depend on the data they were trained on. So the training corpus may have included a lot of names similar to "John Smith", but not enough names similar to "Jay Pratap Pandey" – so the model currently doesn't predict it as a `PERSON` entity. You could [set the entities manually](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#setting-entities) or look into [training and updating the model](https://spacy.io/usage/training) with more examples similar to the names your application needs to recognise.